# "Irreversibility" of the RG flow

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, reversibility

In his remarkable 1986 [work](http://www.jetpletters.ru/ps/1413/article_21504.pdf) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20220619081519/http://www.jetpletters.ru/ps/1413/article_21504.pdf)), Zamolodchikov proved a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-theorem) regarding Renormalization Group (RG) flow in a 2D QFT, describing a monotonically decreasing function in the flow parameter which is equal to the central charge at the flow fixed points (which correspond to conformal field theories).

My question is not about the paper itself but about its title and its common interpretation. The theorem is commonly referred to as an "irreversibility" theorem, and the RG flow is said to be "irreversible" in some sense.

In what sense is the flow irreversible? What is the meaning of an RG flow being irreversible? What is the virtue of the (ir)reversibility of a RG flow?

Comment: Hi @itamarhason, it would be helpful for other readers if you defined the acronyms/initialisms used in your question (e.g., to what does RG refer?).  It is also (often) helpful if you put your question(s) in a separate paragraph or place it alone (just easier to read).

Comment: @honeste_vivere - thanks, I tried to clarify what was not so clear before, and to separate the question from the intro.

Comment: I glanced at the article and would like to point out a subtlety that is often overlooked.  When one calculates a correlation or performs an ensemble average, both typically denoted by the $\langle \rangle$ symbol around some terms, one inserts irreversibility into the equations.  The dynamics themselves may already have real irreversibility, but the act of correlating or averaging things, by definition, results in irreversibility.

Comment: The irreversibility should be of the RG flow, not of the temporal dynamics.

Comment: That is fine, I was just pointing out a consequence of the chosen mathematics.

Comment: By the way, the importance of an irreversible process relates to energy dissipation and entropy production.

Comment: This use of the word "irreversibility" has nothing to do with the irreversibility of time evolution and the second law. The RG flow is in principle fully reversible, although in practice there is some ``loss'' of information. For example, if your low energy effective action is a theory of Goldstone bosons then you may not be able to reconstruct the underlying microscopic theory that led to spontaneous symmetry breaking (some of its operators flowed to zero).

Comment: What the paper tries to formalize is the notion that there is a direction to RG flow. In particular, by computing certain observables we can determine whether we are flowing to the IR or the UV. Intuitively, this observable counts the number of degrees of freedom, making precise the idea that at low energy there should always be fewer (or at most equal number) degrees of freedom than at high energy.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @Qmechanic, the link can be very easily reconstructed since it's referred to in wikipedia (for which I gave a link too) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to the question is basically that not only the flow itself cannot be reversed, but more generally, and maybe more clearly, there is no flow which could take you in the reverse way, no matter what is the suggested path.
Since there is a decreasing function characterizing *any* flow, then any RG flow violating this decreasing fashion is forbidden. In that sense the flow is irreversible - in the sense that a flow has a direction, and flowing in the opposite direction is impossible.

Comment: I think that it’s almkst true, I suggest to read https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2649